# Flags and poles with 2 types of flags

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we place $r$ red flags and $b$ blue ones on $n$ flagpoles? Flags of the same color are indistinguishable, but the pattern of red/blue flags on each pole is important.

I'm thinking we first arrange the number of flags on the ground. The number of ways to do that would be $\frac{(r + b)!}{r!b!}$ and then we would multiply the number of ways to add poles to the in between the flags and the ways for that would be $\binom{r+b+1}{n}$ as there are a total of $r+b+1$ possible positions for the poles. Does this make any sense?

Comment: The protocol on this forum is that you first show what effort you have put in and where you are stuck

Comment: I'm thinking we first arrange the number of flags on the ground. The umber if ways to do that would be (r+b)!/r!b! and then we would multiply the number of ways to add poles to the in between the flags and the ways for that would be r+b+1 choose n as there are a total of r+b+1possible positions for the poles. Does this make any sense?

Comment: You can write `$\frac{(r + b)!}{r!b!}$` to obtain $\frac{(r + b)!}{r!b!}$.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Lets think your answer using similar way. Lets assume that we have $k$ indistinguishable white marbles where $k = b+r$,i.e, the number of white marbles is equal to sum of number of red and blue flags.

Now using [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) , distribute these $k$ marbles into $n$ boxes ,i.e , flagpoles. We can do it $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{n+r+b-1}{r+b}$$

(Think that when we distribute these marbles , we arrange them in a straight line)

Now , lets put our flags onto these white indistingusihable marbles. We can do it by $$\frac{(r+b)!}{r!\times b!}$$

So , the answer is $$\binom{n+r+b-1}{r+b} \times \frac{(r+b)!}{r!\times b!} $$

Comment: Have a look at my answer now ?

Comment: @trueblueanil i do not understand why you assumed that there must be at least one flag , but anyway it does not matter. f you say $n=r=b=2$ , try to list possible arrangements by brute force , you will see your error

Comment: I mistakenly took $n$ to be flags and solved a problem with a different flavor ! Anyway, goodnight from here ! $\;\;$ +:)

Comment: @trueblueanil thank you , goodnight :)